# PHP Regex: Matching Specific Words Within Html

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have this html code:

```
<html>
<div class="the_grp">
<h3>heading <span id="sn-sin" class="the_decs">(keyword: <i>cat</i>)</span></h3>
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <div><span class="w_pos"></span></div>
            <div class="w_the">
            <a href="http://www.exampledomain.com/20111/cute-cat">cute cat</a>, 
            <a href="http://www.exampledomain.com/7456/catty">catty</a>, 
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>   
    <li>
        <div>
            <div><span class="w_pos"></span></div>
            <div class="w_the">
            <a href="http://www.exampledomain.com/7589/sweet">sweet</a>, 
            <a href="http://www.exampledomain.com/10852/sweet-cat">sweet cat</a>, 
            <a href="http://www.exampledomain.com/20114/cat-vs-dog">cat vs dog</a>, 
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

<a id="ant"></a>
<div class="the_grp">
<h3>another heading <span id="sn-an" class="the_decs">(ignore this: <i>cat</i>)</span></h3>
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <div><span class="w_pos"></span></div>
            <div class="w_the"><a href="http://www.exampledomain.com/118/bad-cat">bad cat</a></div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

i want to match the following words from the html code:

- cute cat
- catty
- sweet
- sweet cat
- cat vs dog

i'm using this pattern and capturing [2] to get those words:

```
#<a href="http\:(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a>#i
```

my php code looked like this:

```
preg_match_all('#<a href="http\:(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a>#i', $data, $matches);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches[2]);
echo '</pre>';
```

That pattern match "bad cat" too. How to capture only this following words: cute cat, catty, sweet, sweet cat, cat vs dog?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll refer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Don't use regex for parsing HTML.

Comment: The pattern that you're using will match everything inside `a`. The thing that you're trying to do is scraping, just look for a PHP library for this.

Comment: @MikeVelazco i use simple html dom before, i still can't find solution because those words stay in same div class.

Comment: I'm not a Regex epert, but you can replace the second `(.*?)` with `(cute cat|catty|sweet|sweet cat|cat vs dog)`

Answer (score 0):

It would be best just to use an HTML parser.  Here's how you do it by using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/.

`file_get_html` would be preferably, it will go basically call file_get_contents and `str_get_html`,

`str_get_html` is how you can parse string to an simple html dom object.

```
<?php

require('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = str_get_html(/*your html here*/);

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->plaintext  . '<br>';

?>
```

And if you don't want bad cat to match, simply loop through the results and remove/ignore it that way.

And if you want to remove `bad cat`:

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
    if ($element->plaintext != "bad cat")
       echo $element->plaintext  . '<br>';
```